# Get the height of title bar shown in PCL visualizer

Tags: vtk, point-cloud-library

I have a [PCL Visualizer](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php) window as shown below-

[image]

I want to get the height of the title bar. I can get the height of visualizer window using `camera.window_size[1]` where `camera` is an instance of `pcl::visualization::Camera`.

**My question is that how to get the height of title bar?**

I am using PCL version 1.7.1.

Comment: Any comments, please?

Comment: What you are asking depends of your OS and (as you seem to be using Linux) of your window manager. Your question is not related to VTK or PCL in my opinion.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers: Ya I realized that. However, can you tell me where exactly or what exactly I should look into? If the height of the title bar is OS dependent, then it should be accessible using C/ C++?